# How to change the precision of a polygon in ElasticSearch when querying?

Tags: solr, geolocation, elasticsearch, polygon, precision

I have documents indexed which are all located using a field having set the `geo_point` type. Now I am querying the documents using a geo polygon filter.

Is it possible to change the precision of the polygons used to query the documents?

When I am indexing polygons I am able to change the precision using the `precision` or the `distance_error_pct` option. See: [geo shape maping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-shape-type.html). I could also use indexed shapes to query documents using [pre-indexed shapes](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-filter.html#_pre_indexed_shape) but this is not an option because I do not want to index a polygon before making a request and I experienced that the geo shape filter is not as fast as the geo polygon filter. The geo shape filter would also require the points to be a `geo_shape` type and I am using the geo bounding box filter together with the geo polygon filter.

In Solr I am able to change the precision of a polygon used for a query by specifying distErrPct or distErr (see: [SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4#Search)). I would like to do something like this with ElasticSearch but was not able to find such an option.